# copying files in C program?

Tags: c, file, file-copying

Im trying to copy a mal file to a text file. So basically I want the contents of the mal file to copy over to the text file. the mal file is name test1.mal and the txt file is name output.txt. This is what I have but it keeps printing out error reading the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(void) {

char content[255];
char newcontent[255];

FILE *fp1, *fp2;
fp1 = fopen("test1.mal", "r");
fp2 = fopen("output.txt", "w");

if(fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL)
{
printf("error reading file\n");
exit(0);
}
printf("files open correct\n");
while(fgets(content, sizeof (content), fp1) !=NULL)
{
fputs(content, stdout);
strcpy (content, newcontent);
}

printf("%s", newcontent);
printf("text received\n");

while(fgets(content, sizeof(content), fp1) !=NULL)
{
fprintf(fp2, newcontent);
}
printf("file created and text copied");

fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's because file doesn't exist in the current directory (that you should try to print using `getcwd()`)

Comment: `if(fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL)` are you sure ?

Comment: Use `perror` instead of `printf` to print the error message.  That will tell you **why** the preceding function call failed.  Also, do the error check separately for each `fopen` call so you know which one failed.

Comment: Check this line ==>> `fprintf(fp2, newcontent)` too.

Comment: If only the folks who made `fopen` provided some way to figure out *why* it failed.

Comment: `if(fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL)` tests whether input file cannot be opened or output file cannot be created. I wouldn't test both conditions together.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? The executable file must be in the same folder of the file, otherwise it will fail. If you are using, for instance, code::blocks it will create the executable in the bin\Debug folder, so you would need to place your files there.

Comment: @Michi I changed that line to ---> fprintf(fp2, "output.txt"); and now it says it copied it but when I open the file nothing from the other file has been copied over

Comment: calling function `exit()` with a parameter of 0 is normally used to indicate success, but if any of the calls to fopen() failed, then it was not successful,  Suggest: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   Where `EXIT_FAILURE` is found in stdlib.h

Comment: Note `strcpy()` copies from right to left not left to right.  And the '%s' format specifier will stop outputting when it encounters a '\0' char,  STRONGLY suggest using `read()` and `write()`, especially the `write()` for transferring the file contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files in C program, but file is blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267023/copying-files-in-c-program-but-file-is-blank)

Comment: Why does your error message get written to stdout instead of stderr?  Why does it say "error reading file" when you haven't even attempted to read the file?  ("open" != "read").  Why do you expect the second read loop to do anything?  If the first read loop terminated, you should expect the second loop to terminate immediately, and no data will ever be written.  Why have you asked this question a second time instead of taking the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267023/copying-files-in-c-program-but-file-is-blank/43267564?noredirect=1#comment73604112_43267564?

Comment: Don't forget to look at the `sendfile` function, highly efficient copy.

Answer (score 3):

The posted code has several problems, many of which are expressed in the comments to the OP's question.

The following code is one way to perform the desired operation.

It cleanly compiles and performs appropriate error checking

Note: the calls to `perror()` will output, to `stderr`, the enclosed text and the reason the OS thinks the operation failed.

Note: used `open()`, `close()`, `read()`, `write()` because there is no guarantee that the input .mal file does not contain embedded NUL characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>    // perror()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE


#include <unistd.h>   // read(), write(), close()
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>    // open()

// declare the size of the buffers with a meaningful name
// do not use 'magic' numbers
#define BUFF_SIZE 255

int main(void)
{

    char content[ BUFF_SIZE ];

    int fin;
    int fout;

    if( 0 > (fin = open("test1.mal", O_RDONLY) ) )
    {
        perror( "open for read of test1.mal failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, open successful

    if( 0 > (fout = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY) ) )
    {
        perror( "open for write of output.txt failed");
        close( fin );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    printf("files open correct\n");

    ssize_t readCount;
    while( 0 < (readCount = read( fin, content, sizeof( content) ) ) )
    {
        //fputs(content, stdout);  // are you sure the file contents are printable?
        if( readCount != write( fout, content, (size_t)readCount ) )
        { // then write error occured
            perror( "write of data to output file failed" );
            close( fin );
            close( fout );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, write successful
    }

    if( 0 > readCount )
    { // then read error occurred
        perror( "read of file failed" );
        close( fin );
        close( fout );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, complete file copied

    printf("file created and text copied\n");

    close( fin );
    close( fout );
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: You probably should add `O_CREAT` and `O_TRUNC` and a `mode` argument to `open("output.txt", O_WRONLY)`.  Perhaps `open("output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666)`.  Yes, I know - `0666` should use mode flags instead of a magic number...

Comment: @AndrewHenle,  As I understand it, the `O_WRONLY` will handle if the file already exists or not and will truncate an existing file, so `O_TRUNC` not needed.  I must admit I'm so used to having my environment setup to give owner and group read and write permissions and world read permission that I didn't even think about specifying a permissions parameter

Comment: `O_WRONLY` means "open for writing only", and only that.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/  Without `O_CREAT`, `open()` will not create the file. And without `O_TRUNC`, it will not truncate the file.  `open()` is not like `fopen()`. `fopen()` will implicitly create or truncate files based on the arguments passed, but `open()` doesn't act that way.  And if `open()` is passed `O_CREAT`, you need to pass a mode parameter because if the file is created, `open()` will use whatever garbage it finds where the `mode` argument should be as the new file's permissions.

Comment: @AndrewHenle,  Good to know, thanks for clarification